# How to set textstyle for linechart using coreplot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using coreplot 0.9 .I had tried setting linecolor property for CPTLineStyle by

But it is giving error that color or fontSize is readonly property. Please give me some solution for this.

```
  static CPTTextStyle *labelTextStyle= nil ;
  labelTextStyle = [[CPTTextStyle alloc]init];
  labelTextStyle.color =[CPTColor whiteColor];
   labelTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0f ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CPTMutableTextStyle`. In Core Plot, text styles, line styles, shadows, and numeric data objects come in two variants—mutable and immutable. This follows the pattern common to many Cocoa objects like `NSString` and `NSArray`.